# What's going on with the "DO NOT CLICK LINK" message?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, hyperlinks

What's going on with the "**DO NOT CLICK LINK**" message on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240514/what-would-be-a-nice-modal-box-for-an-asp-website)? What is "SLASH SLASS"?

[image: screenshot of page reading "DO NOT CLICK THIS LINK: http COLON SLASH SLASS www.e-magine..."]

Answer (score 3):

The link seems to be potentially harmful to the clicker's computer.  That is why it was removed from the post.

I changed the way the link is presented. It still isn't clickable though, just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Being the daredevil that I am, I clicked it. It says don't click because the site is flagged as malware.

Comment: Same here.

Comment: Don't think about pink elephants!

Comment: I was wondering about the "SLASH SLASS" message hahaha

Comment: it was a typo

Comment: @jjnguy is the typo built into the system (was that an automated comment)

Comment: Nope, John made the typo when he made the link un-clickble.  You can view the edit history here: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1240514/list

Answer (score 0):

It was edited, if you click on the link that says 'edited ...' then you'll see the edit history.